# I sent ethereum to a cold wallet address that does not support the bep20 network,

Tags: erc-20

I sent ethereum to a cold wallet address that does not support the bep20 network, can it be patched to erc20

Answer (score 0):

Cold wallet doesn't have to support it. As long as you have access to the `pk` or `mnemonic phrase` of that wallet, you can access ERC20, BEP20, etc...

You can also access bscscan.com and search your wallet address, and you'll see those tokens under `Tokens` section.

Simple way to do it is either:

- Writing a script to transfer that tokens somewhere, and signing transaction with `pk`.
- Importing `pk` into Metamask, connecting to BinanceSmartChain, and seeing it present in your wallet -> But then cold storage pk looses it's purpose, as at the moment it touches MM it's considered exposed to the internet.

Hope this is helpful enough.